# Function in a dataframe comparing two column

Tags: r, dataframe, as.date

I have a data frame with three column. I want to apply a function to compare the second and third column, my function will create a new column.
With an example :

```
vin <- c("vin1", "vin2", "vin3", "vin4")
date.fin.obs <- rep(as.Date("2014-07-04"), length(vin))
date.fin <- c(as.Date("2014-07-04"), as.Date("2013-03-21"), as.Date("2013-07-06"),
             as.Date("2014-07-04"))
df <- data.frame(vin, date.fin.obs, date.fin)

CumulSurvivants <- function(x, y){
#   y <- length(x)
  x.num <- as.numeric(x)
  y.num <- as.numeric(y)

#   i <- length(x)
  i <- 0
  if(x.num == y.num){
    return(i)
  }else{
    return(i+1)
  }


}

CumulSurvivants(x = df$date.fin[2], y = df$date.fin.obs[4])
```

seems to work, but I want to compare the two column row by row, and to write the result of my function in a new column.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of output are you looking for?

Comment: Why are you using row 2 and row 4 in your example?

Comment: yes in my example it's row 2 and 4

Comment: Does it make any sense?

Comment: @AnandaMahto, i'm lookink for a new column in my data frame where i can see the result of the function for each row

Comment: If you simply do `df$tdiff <- as.numeric(sign(with(df, date.fin.obs-date.fin)))`?

Comment: @MostafaRifi, sorry--still don't understand. Please update your question with some sample output.

Comment: @AnandaMahto,Pascal, I complicated myself, the difference between the two column solved the problem. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compute the date difference, you may simply use

```
df$difference <- date.fin.obs - date.fin
```

resulting in

```
   vin date.fin.obs   date.fin difference
1 vin1   2014-07-04 2014-07-04     0 days
2 vin2   2014-07-04 2013-03-21   470 days
3 vin3   2014-07-04 2013-07-06   363 days
4 vin4   2014-07-04 2014-07-04     0 days
```

Or, instead of the simple "minus", use any other more specialized date/time function in the same way, possibly with date/time formatting. Also have a look at `?strptime` and http://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html.